# Cordova iOS 6.1.1 white splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, config, splash-screen

In my Cordova app, I have a problem after upgrading to cordova-ios 6.1.1.
The app runs correctly, but the splash screen isn't showed. There is only a white screen, like if my splash screen files are ignored.

I have this config.xml file:

```
<widget id="xxx" version="x" versionCode="x" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>xxx</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="xxx@xxx.com" href="http://www.xx.com/">xxx</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-10.0.0" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <!--<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />-->
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <!--<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />-->
  <!--<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />-->
  
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  
  
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
  <!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" onload="true" />-->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release">
  </plugin>
  
  
  <!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" />
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts" value="on" />
    <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
  </platform>-->
  
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost"  /> 
  
    <!-- <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-xhr" />
  <platform name="ios">
     <preference name="NativeXHRLogging" value="none" />
     <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
     <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
     <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
     <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
  </platform>-->
 
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
  <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" version="*" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner">
    <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xxx." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xxx." />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xxx." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-exit" />

  <access origin="*" />
    
  <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx.</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx.</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config target="CFBundleShortVersionString" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx</string>
  </edit-config>
  <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.iTunesArtwork.png"/>

  <platform name="android">
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_36_36.png" density="ldpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_48_48.png" density="mdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_72_72.png"  density="hdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_96_96.png"  density="xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_200_320.png"  density="port-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_480.png"  density="port-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_800.png"  density="port-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_720_1280.png"  density="port-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_200.png"  density="land-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_320.png"  density="land-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_800_480.png"  density="land-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_720.png"  density="land-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40~ipad.png" width="40" height="40" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40@3x.png" width="120" height="120" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon50x50~ipad.png" width="50" height="50" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon50x50@2x~ipad.png" width="100" height="100" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29.png" width="29" height="29" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29@3x.png" width="87" height="78" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.iTunesArtwork.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
  </platform>
  
  
</widget>
```

Do you see any errors or problems here? I read a lot of solutions and tried them all, but my problem is still here.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in IOS 14. But its working below IOS 14. Did you tried updating Xcode to latest version?

Comment: I make online build. I use VolBuilder and this tool has already all updated...

Comment: @saravana I did it, look my own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it!!!!!

First of all, keep in mind you have to use only one image for the iOS splash screen, although the [Cordova docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) says you can also use multiple images like in the past.

So, in the root folder you need this:

```
res
  |-- screen
        |--ios
        |--android
```

In the iOS folder, create an image called Default@2x~universal~anyany.png with your splash screen with 2732x2732 pixels resolution.

Then add this in your config.xml

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
```

and delete the old references to other iOS splash files (not for icons files, that part didn't changed).

I also removed the reference to the plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen since in cordova iOS 6.1.1 is already included. --> EDIT: this work in iOS, but you have to keep the following line to make it work in Android:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
```

Note that Default@2x~universal~anyany.png has to be an image with your logo or something else in its center, since the border area will be cropped when showed. You have to do some tries in different devices to find out what is better for your splash screen image.

Comment: Thank you @Piero its working now. Res folder already available in project root folder I didn't noticed previously.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem too! It looks like for some reason you must follow the naming convention even if passing the src attribute. Splash screen file name must be one of those listed in the plugin examples.

Comment: The docs for this plugin state:
"If your launch image is simple, you may be able to avoid creating a lot of different launch images and supply only one. The launch image needs to meet the following requirements:

the image should be square
the image should be large enough to fit on an iPad Pro 12.9": 2732x2732
anything important should fit within the center
Keep in mind that the image will be cropped, possibly quite severely, depending upon the viewport."

Comment: @ghenne another important point to mention is that the image cannot be called whatever you want it has to follow these naming guidelines: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#multi-image-launch-screen

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to open the Xcode project in Xcode built from Cordova command line, drag the images, and run the emulator from Xcode.

[image: open images-xcassets directory inside resources in Xcode project]

[image: Open Launch storyboard images directory inside resources in Xcode]

[image: Drag images in the launch story board window.]