# Cordova Android white splash screen

Tags: android, image, cordova, splash-screen

Some time ago I asked (and solved) for the same question for the iOS version fo my app ([Cordova iOS 6.1.1 white splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141434/cordova-ios-6-1-1-white-splash-screen/64174737)), now I have the same issue for the Android one.

I'm build the apk with an online tool using cordova-cli-10.0.0

The app runs but I see only a white screen instead of my splash screen file.

In my config.xml file I have the following splash screen settings (I skipped other settings here, if needed I can post them):

```
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <platform name="android">
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_800.png" density="hdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_200_320.png" density="ldpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_480.png" density="mdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_720_1280.png" density="xhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_960_1600.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_1920.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>

      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_800_480.png"  density="land-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_200.png"  density="land-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_320.png"  density="land-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_720.png"  density="land-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1600_960.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1920_1280.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_800.png"  density="port-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_200_320.png"  density="port-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_480.png"  density="port-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_720_1280.png"  density="port-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_960_1600.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_1920.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_800_480.png"  density="land-night-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_200.png"  density="land-night-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_320.png"  density="land-night-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_720.png"  density="land-night-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1600_960.png" density="land-night-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1920_1280.png" density="land-night-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_800.png"  density="port-night-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_200_320.png"  density="port-night-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_480.png"  density="port-night-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_720_1280.png"  density="port-night-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_960_1600.png" density="port-night-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_1920.png" density="port-night-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_36_36.png" density="ldpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_48_48.png" density="mdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_72_72.png"  density="hdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_96_96.png"  density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
```

I added the xxhdpi and xxxhdpi files and also the dark mode settings, but it is still a white splash screen. Can you please help me here?

UPDATE

Here my whole config.xml file

```
<widget id="com.xxx.xxx" version="1.1.22" versionCode="22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>xxx</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="info@xxx.com" href="xxx">xxx</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-10.0.0" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <!--<preference name = "SplashScreen" value = "screen" />-->
  <feature name="LaunchScreen">
     <param name="ios-package" value="LaunchScreenStoryboard" onload="true" />
     <preference name="StoryboardName" value="LaunchScreen" />
     <preference name="FadeOut" value="true" />
     <preference name="FadeOutDuration" value="1" />
   </feature>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm">
    <param name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xxx." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="28.0.0"/>
  </plugin>
  <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="localhost"  /> 
  <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" version="*" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2"/><!-- source="git" spec="https://github.com/neptsoft/cordova-plugin-file-opener2" />-->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-exit" />
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
  </platform>
  <edit-config target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config target="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>xxx</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config target="CFBundleShortVersionString" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>1.1.22</string>
  </edit-config>
  <platform name="android">
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_480_800.png" density="hdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_200_320.png" density="ldpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_320_480.png" density="mdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_720_1280.png" density="xhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_960_1600.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1280_1920.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>

      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_800_480.png"  density="land-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_320_200.png"  density="land-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_480_320.png"  density="land-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1280_720.png"  density="land-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1600_960.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1920_1280.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_480_800.png"  density="port-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_200_320.png"  density="port-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_320_480.png"  density="port-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_720_1280.png"  density="port-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_960_1600.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1280_1920.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_800_480.png"  density="land-night-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_320_200.png"  density="land-night-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_480_320.png"  density="land-night-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1280_720.png"  density="land-night-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1600_960.png" density="land-night-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1920_1280.png" density="land-night-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_480_800.png"  density="port-night-hdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_200_320.png"  density="port-night-ldpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_320_480.png"  density="port-night-mdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_720_1280.png"  density="port-night-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_960_1600.png" density="port-night-xxhdpi"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android_splash_1280_1920.png" density="port-night-xxxhdpi"/>
      
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_36_36.png" density="ldpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_48_48.png" density="mdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_72_72.png"  density="hdpi" />
      <icon src="res/screen/android/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_96_96.png"  density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.iTunesArtwork.png"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-88@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40~ipad.png" width="40" height="40" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon40x40@3x.png" width="120" height="120" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon50x50~ipad.png" width="50" height="50" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon50x50@2x~ipad.png" width="100" height="100" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29.png" width="29" height="29" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.AppIcon29x29@3x.png" width="87" height="78" />
      <icon src="res/screen/ios/PackageIcons.iOS.iTunesArtwork.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
  </platform>
  
</widget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use proper file naming, rename your

```
PackageIcons.Android.splash_1280_1920.png
```

To

```
PackageIcons_Android_splash_1280_1920.png
```

**I also don't see `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^6.0.0" />` you need to install it**

Comment: paste your entire config.xml please, also what version of the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, clue found.

I removed the reference to the plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen since in cordova iOS 6.1.1 is already included. BUT, this work in iOS, you have to keep the following line to make it work in Android:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
```

After I added, the splash screen is showed.

Comment: Dude, that was in my answer

Comment: @Eric ops, you are right... I just set your answer as the solution. Excuse me. ps. can you upvote my answer so the downvote is useless? Thanks

Comment: Will do in a few hours, it won't let me right now